# Increase the maximum line length / column length on VSCode (10000 by default)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a very long JSON string.

On VSCode only the first 10000 characters of a line can be displayed, an ellipsis is shown when the line exceeds 10000 characters, see the screenshot below :

[image: VSCODe line length]

Is it possible to change the maximum line length / column length in the settings?

I actually need to see more of this string because `JSON.parse()` doesn't work, there's an error at position 11000, I could use another text editor like Notepad++ to see the rest of the string but I still want to know if it is possible to change the maximum line length / column length in the settings, in the meantime I'll use Notepad++.

Comment: I've answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50863170/9374673) as it was asked again by another user.

Comment: Thank you very much @MihaiChelaru, have a nice day !

Comment: @MihaiChelaru Could you also post your answer here even if you have already posted the answer in another question? I just saw that my question was seen 3k times, and doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of [How to show full long line in visual studio code (word wrap off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862347/how-to-show-full-long-line-in-visual-studio-code-word-wrap-off), as cross-posting answers is frowned upon, and this way your question can serve as a signpost to the answer that helped you. I regret that I originally did not realize your question already existed when I answered the other one, since you did ask yours first.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru No problem. I am ok with that, a duplicate message box with a link to the original answer is more visible than a link in the comments.

Comment: I believe you can accept the duplicate yourself. I should have marked it as such back when I posted the comment but I felt bad because your question predated the other one. Thanks for the suggestion!