# How to show full long line in visual studio code (word wrap off)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to view complete long line (on a single line) in visual studio code. The editor is terminating the line with `...` at the end.

I can press the `End` key to move to the last column of the line but its not visible in the viewport.

Is there any option to be able to view complete long lines like we can in Sublime Text or Notepad++?

[image: VS Code long line]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The answer is in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7772#issuecomment-347174463):

> The current recommendation is to turn on word wrapping if the intent
>   is to edit past the 10k limit or change the limit via the "hidden"
>   setting "editor.stopRenderingLineAfter" which is equal to 10000 by
>   default, but which can be changed to -1 to never stop rendering. But
>   then freezes/lagging might occur.

In other words, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open up the Command Palette, select **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)**, and add the following line:

```
"editor.stopRenderingLineAfter" : -1
```

If you want to set a hard limit just change the -1 to whatever number of characters you want. Note that you might still get wrapping happening if you haven't disabled it, which you can toggle with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> or using the other methods mentioned in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028495/9374673).

Comment: I'm not getting the toknization errors if I turn off this setting: "editor.largeFileOptimizations": false

Comment: Pressing CTRL + , does not allow adding a new line because it does not lead to a text file, instead it leads to GUI settings.

Comment: @Preza8 That's a good point. Since I posted this answer, the User settings UI has changed and it looks like you can't even search for this setting in there. As such, it would be better to use the command palette and open up **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)** and make the change there.

Comment: That's no longer supported, `largeFileOptimizations` did the trick for me

Comment: @nikksan Do you have a link to an official source saying the feature's no longer supported? If not, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @MihaiChelaru I didn't read the full answer and assumed it was not supported when the IDE didn't recognize it.

Comment: It work, though it's gray in user's settings.json.

Answer (score 18):

Try using: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>

unwrapped code

[image: unwrapped code]

wrapped code

[image: wrapped code]

Comment: this was my problem TYVM, idk why but suddenly every time I open VSC my code is wrapped.

Comment: Thank you.  Better than messing with preferences for a one-off.

Comment: in mac it was `Option+z`

Answer (score 0):

On version 1.41.1 you can set `Editor: Word Wrap` to `on` inside `Preferences/Settings`. To go to Settings, use `Cmd` + `,` in Mac and `Ctrl` + `,` in Windows.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which explicitly states "word wrap off." Turning on word wrap defeats the point.

Answer (score -1):

In other words, use CTRL + SHIFT + P to open up the Command Palette, select Preferences: Open Settings (JSON), and add the following line:

"editor.wordWrap": "on"

Comment: the question asked solution for "word wrap off"