# How to search for a specific position in a JSON file?

Tags: node.js, json, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to import a large JSON file but I'm getting this error:

```
Unexpected token , in JSON at position 197031914
```

how do i go to that position to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an older question but since its getting some views I want to mention how I ended up solving this issue.

Because I was processing huge files (gigabytes), it was not working with linters, so I ended up solving this issue by writing my script that takes a readable stream and find that position and then return the context (x number of charachters before and after position).

I still use it and I might get around to publish it on npm for others to use. (not sure if someone had already done a similar thing);

Comment: If you have time, please publish code. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 12):

Besides the recommendations of using a json linter, [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jtr.vscode-position) lets you navigate to a specific offset (position) within a file. You'd want to go to offset `197031914`.

Keep in mind that if the file has very long lines, VS Code will not display the entire line. You can try adjusting this limit [by following these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862347/how-to-show-full-long-line-in-visual-studio-code-word-wrap-off)

Comment: This extension doesn't seem to work on large files.

Comment: For me this works flawlessly on a 30mb .json file. Thank you!

Comment: @Metomorphose Another similar extension, which might work on larger files, is show-offset: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ramyaraoa.show-offset

Answer (score 4):

Just use a JSON linter.  There are plenty online, like [this one](https://jsonlint.com/).  The linter will point out the specific errors in the syntax of your JSON file.

Comment: I'm dealing with larger than 1G files. I can't even open the file to copy the content to the linter

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are your JSON files so large?

Comment: they are patent datasets that I had converted from XML to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a one line file. There is an out-of-the-box command to jump to a line number in VS Code. But there is not for a jump to column. So, simply add [this VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salman-hasrat.jumptocolumn) to be able to easily jump to a given column on line.

Comment: it is actually a JSON file where each object in the array is on a new line. I guess when node is importing it, it is first seeing it as a one line string before parsing it. I know that because the error is occurring inside the try block wheere JSON.parse(content) is taking called on the content inside the loader.js module.

Comment: I think node fails when it find the broken JSON string. As I said, install the VS Code extension and check the problematic JSON file. You'll find out right away. You could also just take that first line in the file and paste it in an online linter like this one: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can auto-fix by linting from the command line using [eslint-plugin-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-json):

```
$ npm i eslint eslint-plugin-json
$ npx eslint --fix example.json
```

*NOTE: You can get more info about the issue using `npx eslint example.json` (before fixing).*

Comment: @JLavoie agreed, but comments on other answers suggest that the file is too large to be opened - how do you suggest fixing it manually? I added a way to get more info about the error. Let me know if you have any other suggestions for improvement, thanks!

Comment: In this case open the file with vi or vim. vi can open extremely large files. In vi, assuming the error is one row 1, insert mode enter: `:call cursor(1, 197031914)`